# Problem to update a value in Access Database

Tags: c#

I'm coding a small program with C# to watch my organization's cars and I use code below to update value but it didn't work when I apply it.

```
OleDbCommand updateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Mqar SET [Car_Type] = @Car_Type,[Model] = @Model,[chase_nu] = @chase_nu,[Engin_Nu] = @Engin_Nu,[Car_nu] = @Car_nu,[Car_State] = @Car_State,[Draiver_Name] = @Draiver_Name,WHERE [ID] = @ID", conn);
conn.Open();
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Car_Type", textBox1.Text);
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", textBox2.Text);
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chase_nu", textBox3.Text);
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Engin_Nu", textBox4.Text);
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Car_nu", textBox5.Text);
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Car_State", comboBox1.Text);
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Draiver_Name", textBox6.Text);
//updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text));
//conn.Open();
updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("تم تعديل بيانات الالية بنجاح");
connaction();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: The SQL is not correct, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update statement is not correct because there is a comma before the `where` keyword.

Change the SQL like this:

`UPDATE Mqar SET [Car_Type] = @Car_Type,[Model] = @Model,[chase_nu] = @chase_nu,[Engin_Nu] = @Engin_Nu,[Car_nu] = @Car_nu,[Car_State] = @Car_State,[Draiver_Name] = @Draiver_Name WHERE [ID] = @ID`

Notice I removed a comma before `,WHERE` => `WHERE`

Also notice that there is an @ID parameter, so you need to pass that too, so uncomment this line:

`updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text));`

---

Extra advice (not an answer to your question):

You need to name your variables/input elements in a way that reflects that they are used for.

For example, `textBox1` is a bad name because the name does not tell you what it is supposed to be, is it a Car Name? An ID? A model name?

You should rename all the input elements (text boxes and combo boxes) to something meaningful like:

`textBox1` => `carTypeText`

`comboxBox1` => `carStateComboBox`

The clarity you will gain from properly named variables will help you avoid bugs.

Comment: If the resolution is a grand total of 3 characters removed from the source code, I'd vote to close as a typo.